# CKEditor File Upload in aspx

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ckeditor

I've been searching for ages for a solution with no luck..
I'm working with CKEditor on my asp.net and I need to add a file upload option.
So far I've found solutions for php only, which does not work in my case.
Is there a possibility to this for aspx??

Thanx
Avi

Answer (score 0):

You need CKFinder for this I implemented earlier but I don't have exact  code You can find more [here](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/CKEditor_Integration)